# Using icon in component prop object in Storybook crash browser

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Didn't find anything about this question, so I will appreciate any help/ideas from you.

I have simple input component in `stories.tsx` like this one:

```
export const Icon: Story<InputProps> = (args) => {
  ...

  return (
    <Input
      ...
      rightIcon={{ icon: <OpenEyeIcon size="medium" /> }}
    />
  );
};
```

Using construction in rightIcon prop is what I need and it works good in my app and when I watching stories. But when I try to use this component in `docs.mdx` like this:

```
<Canvas>
  <Story id="components-input--icon" />
</Canvas>
```

it crash the browser and timeout error occur.
This is not the problem about webpack loader that has many issues in github, I've tried to specify loader for storybook, but it wont help.

Fun things happens when I declare component outside of the story like this:

```
const IconComponent = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <Input
      ...
      rightIcon={{ icon: <OpenEyeIcon size="medium" /> }}
    />
  );
}

export const Icon: Story<InputProps> = (args) => {
  return <IconComponent />
}
```

And this works as intended.
Any other components work from story without problem, problem occurs only when I use icon inside of object. I tried this on storybook versions 6.4.x, 6.5.x (latest by now).

Any ideas why this happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Can you put the error as well?

Comment: There no any cpecific errors at console. Browser just show message that this page stuck and need to stop it.